# secant root finder problems

Tags: matlab, variables, for-loop

I'm not sure how to get this result to move/copy data between three variables:

```
loop1  x=new y=old 
loop2  z=new  x=old
```

Here is my code:

```
clc;
  clear;
 format long;
 x=input('input  high guess:      ');
 y=input('input low guess:      ');    
 N=100;
 P=1;
 T=[];
 for i= 1:N

f1=(x.^3)-(2*x.^2)-(4*x)+8;
f2=(y.^3)-(2*y.^2)-(4*y)+8;
 z=x-(((f1)*(y-x))/(f2-f1));

  Z=(z.^3)-(2*z.^2)-(4*z)+8;
  x=z;
  y=x;
   T=[T;z];

   end

   disp(T);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your polynomial looks to be in the form of `x^3 - 2x^2 - 4x + 8`. Let's start by saying there are easier ways to find its roots in Matlab, for example using the [roots function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) as follows:

```
x = -100:100;
y = (x.^3) - (2 .* x.^2) - (4 .* x) + 8;
r = roots([1 -2 -4 8])

r =
    -2.00000000000000
     1.99999998974515
     2.00000001025485
```

Anyway, let's focus on the secant method. The first things you should define are:

- a tolerance level to which your potential result can be tied in order to check if a root has been reached (for example `1e-6`)
- a single anonymous function to express your polynomial, in this case `f = @(x) x^3 - 2*x^2 - 4*x + 8;`

Once this is done, you can build up the whole script:

```
clear();
clc();

com = Inf;
i = 2;
n = 100;
tol = 1e-6;

f = @(x) (x^3) - (2*x^2) - (4*x) + 8;

x(1) = input('Low Guess:     '); 
x(2) = input('High Guess:    ');

while ((abs(com) > tol) && (n > 0))
    com = f(x(i))*(x(i)-x(i-1))/ (f(x(i)) - f(x(i-1)));
    x(i+1)= x(i) - com;

    i = i + 1;
    n = n - 1;
end

display(['Root X = ' num2str(x(end))]);
```

The output is:

```
Low Guess:     0
High Guess:    10
Root X = 2
```